# Kubernetes Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp x.x.x.x:6443: i/o timeout

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I am using test kubenetes cluster (Kubeadm 1 master and 2 nodes setup), My public ip change time to time and when my public IP changed, I am unable to connect to cluster and i get below error

```
 Kubernetes Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp x.x.x.x:6443: i/o timeout
```

I also have private IP 10.10.10.10 which is consistent all the time.

I have created kubernetes cluster using below command

```
 kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint 10.10.10.10
```

But still it failed because certificates are signed to public IP and below is the error

```
 The connection to the server x.x.x.x:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Can someone help to setup kubeadm, and should allow for all IP's something like 0.0.0.0 and I am fine for security view point since it is test setup. or any parament fix.

Comment: I think you won't be able to manage it this way. You need to change the IP and re-generate certs. Take a look at these links: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338#issuecomment-407383077
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338#issuecomment-418879755

Comment: @Vidya Have you solved this problem ?
Have you tried the steps suggested by **mario** ?

Comment: I tried, but it did not worked, it is due to my public ip changing and also using in hyper-v, I just moved to static ip

Answer (score 2):

Since **@Vidya** has already solved this issue by using a static IP address, I decided to provide a Community Wiki answer just for better visibility to other community members.

First of all, it is not recommended to have a frequently changing  master/server IP address.
As we can find in the discussion on GitHub [kubernetes/88648](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/88648) - `kubeadm` does not provide an easy way to deal with this.

However, there are a few workarounds that can help us, when the IP address on the Kubernetes master node changes.
Based on the discussion [Changing master IP address](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338), I prepared a script that regenerates certificates and re-init master node.

This script might be helpful, but I recommend running one command at a time (it will be safer).
In addition, you may need to customize some steps to your needs:
**NOTE:** In the example below, I'm using Docker as the container runtime.

```
root@kmaster:~# cat reinit_master.sh 
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Stopping kubelet and docker"
systemctl stop kubelet docker

echo "Making backup kubernetes data"
mv /etc/kubernetes /etc/kubernetes-backup
mv /var/lib/kubelet /var/lib/kubelet-backup

echo "Restoring certificates"
mkdir /etc/kubernetes
cp -r /etc/kubernetes-backup/pki /etc/kubernetes/
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/{apiserver.*,etcd/peer.*}

echo "Starting docker"
systemctl start docker 


echo "Reinitializing master node"
kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd

echo "Updating kubeconfig file"
cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config
```

Then you need to rejoin the worker nodes to the cluster.