# unable to run kubectl commands against AKS

Tags: ssl, kubectl, azure-aks

All,

"kubectl get nodes" and any kubectl commands is giving the error - "***Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout"***  on my windows laptop. We have SQLServer BDC deployed on AKS and I'm able to connect to the endpoints using Azure Data Studio but I'm unable to run kubectl commands. I tried running the same from BASH shell on the Azure Portal but it gives a different error ***"Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp xx.xxx.xx.xx:443: i/o timeout"***

My coworkers are able to connect and run kubectl commands without any problems.

Thanks,
grajee

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons for Timeout errors.

One of the main reason is:

This might be because of insufficient resources. Try to increase the resource limits in your Docker preferences.

Refer [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64312392/kubernetes-unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-x-x-x-x6443-i-o-timeout) which points toward the network aspect of it where issues were resolved by using a static IP address.

Refer [link](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/14) which is pointing toward the location in which the cluster has been deployed.